# Using Laravel Eloquent to get records from database where the difference of two dates equals a value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There exist a table `users` with a column `hire_date`. The goal is to calculate the difference in years between a user's `hire_date` and a current date in a query.

I want to get records where the difference between `hire_date` as `|1989-10-07 02:06:44|` and now is in an array as `[6,9,30]`

Currently I've tried this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ServiceAwardYear;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class LongServiceAwardController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $records = [9,6];

        foreach($records as $record){

          $employees = User::where(Carbon::parse('hire_date')->diffInYears(Carbon::now()), $record)->get();

     }

}
```

but it returns the error:

`message: "DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (hire_date) at position 0 (h): The timezone could not be found in the database"`. How can I fix this?

Comment: did you want to get the users hire_date is  9years ago and 6 years ago? and your `hire_date` is date type?

Comment: yeah... the `hire_date` column is a `TIMESTAMP`... not just 6 or 9, any number in that array.

Comment: you want get the results exactly 9 or 6 years ago. If they have 1 or 2 secs diff? Or your timestamp's hour, min, sec is all zero?

Comment: I want to get results exactly 6, 9 or any other value in the `$record` `array`. The difference should be in years, not hours, minutes or seconds.

Comment: I have post my answer, plz check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Carbon's `subYears()` to get the date, and compare with `hire_date`, that we can use `date_format` to convert timestamp to date:

```php
$dates_ago = collect([15, 30, 35, 40])->map(function($num) {
    return Carbon::now()->subYears($num)->format('Y-m-d');
})->all();

User::whereIn(\DB::raw("date_format(hire_date, '%Y-%m-%d')"), $dates_ago)->get();
```

Or Just use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

```php
User::whereIn(\DB::raw("TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, hire_date, NOW())"), [15, 30, 35, 40])->get();
```

Comment: `"message": "Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\DB' not found",` I'm using an `API ` Controller

Comment: post `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` or  change `DB` to `\DB`

Comment: There is no error with your query, execpt that even when a record is true in the db, it returns an empty array `[]`

Comment: can u post that record?

Comment: the difference in year, between `|1989-10-07 02:06:44|` and this year is 30. Using your provided query, it is supposed to return true.

Comment: @codervine no, I only filter the date 9,6ago in that date from now. If you want the that I will use less than operator, so do you want all the records before 6 years ago?

Comment: I understand, I have an array of preset values that I'm using your code to test. That is instead of `[$ago_6, $ago_9]` I have mine as `[15, 30, 35, 40]`

Comment: I see your `[$ago_6, $ago_9]` return `date` strings whereas I want to get records where the difference between `hire_date` as `|1989-10-07 02:06:44|` and now is in an array as `[15, 30, 35, 40]`

Comment: @codervine so I think you can debug the `$dates_ago`, I have test, it is working to me

Comment: I will try as you've adviced

Comment: @codervine I have post a second solution if you need it. If the first solution not works to you, I think its your Carbon's timezone is different to your mysql timezone.